# FFMPEG map multiple audio input files to 1 single image file in order to create multiple video output files

Tags: ffmpeg, command, android-ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I am attempting to have multiple output files in ffmpeg map to multiple inputs however instead of each input mapping to a unique output I get the first input mapping to the first video and then the next videos never get created at all, I will describe exactly what I am trying to achieve below,

I need to:

1. create multiple video output files
2. from multiple audio input files
3. which all use the same one common image file to create the
   video

I will post my command below, any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

```
-y -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -f image2 -loop 1 -r 2 -i imagefile.png -shortest -c:a aac -c:v mpeg4 -crf 18 -preset veryfast -movflags faststart -map 0 output1.mp4 -map1 output2.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

## Basic command

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -loop 1 -framerate 10 -i imagefile.png -map 2:v -map 0:a -vf format=yuv420p -shortest output1.mp4 -map 2:v -map 1:a -vf format=yuv420p -shortest output2.mp4
```

The video is filtered and encoded once per output.

## With the [split filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split_002c-asplit)

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -loop 1 -framerate 10 -i imagefile.png -filter_complex "[2:v]format=yuv420p,split=outputs=2[v0][v1]" -map "[v0] -map 0:a -shortest -movflags +faststart output1.mp4 -map "[v1]" -map 1:a -shortest -movflags +faststart output2.mp4
```

The video is filtered once total, and encoded separately for each output.

## Pipe

```
ffmpeg -y -v error -loop 1 -framerate 10 -i imagefile.png -filter_complex "[0:v]format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -c:v libx264 -f nut - | ffmpeg -y -i - -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest -movflags +faststart output1.mp4 -map 0:v -map 2:a -c:v copy -shortest -movflags +faststart output2.mp4
```

The video is filtered and encoded only once and each output stream copies it.